# Prevent from specific app using internet connection

Tags: iphone, connection, asihttprequest

I have a client claims that my app can't connect to internet despite of he has WiFi connection and Safari application, for example, works fine. Is there any way to setup for specific app NOT to connect to the internet? I use in my app simple `ASIHTTTPRequest` library to make a connections. Maybe it influenced by jailbroken device? Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this in via an iOS setting.

However I've had a problem like this with a client, where to Webservice the app connecting to was blocked by there firewall/proxy.

Later the black was lifted but all calls to the webservice where is cached by the proxy give really weird results.